# Any good free website template or theme for wordpress or joomla to demo my phone apps?

Tags: iphone, android, wordpress, demo

I want to build a site to introduce my phone apps and guide users to the app store. is there any good theme or template for me to get start?

I need to put all my apps together and have separate page for single one.

Answer (score 1):

I have 3 app supporting websites all of these are done using wordpress. Generally I found that I pick the template that suits my fancy but one thing I do for sure - enable mobile theme [such as this](http://crowdfavorite.com/wordpress/plugins/wordpress-mobile-edition/) (there are bunch if you search for "wordpress mobile")

I usually create one tab (page) that is loadable from my app and serves as Help page

Comment: None of these websites are valid anymore

Comment: The URLs should be executable but currently are pointing to product pages on G+. Sorry I'm not using wordpress anymore